# Change this a function so I can pass a id into it- javascript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

At the moment I am creating a Hangman Game and I have 26 different functions for each button on the web page. When a button is clicked its function works. What I want to do is change this so all I need is one function for all 26 buttons. Here is my HTML at the moment:

```
           <a href="#" id="A" onclick="A(event)">A</a>
           <a href="#" id="B" onclick="B(event)">B</a>
           <a href="#" id="C" onclick="C(event)">C</a>
           <a href="#" id="D" onclick="D(event)">D</a>
           <a href="#" id="E" onclick="E(event)">E</a>
           <a href="#" id="F" onclick="F(event)">F</a>
           <a href="#" id="G" onclick="G(event)">G</a>
           <a href="#" id="H" onclick="H(event)">H</a>

           <a href="#" id="I" onclick="I(event)">I</a>
           <a href="#" id="J" onclick="J(event)">J</a>
           <a href="#" id="K" onclick="K(event)">K</a>
           <a href="#" id="L" onclick="L(event)">L</a>
           <a href="#" id="M" onclick="M(event)">M</a>

           <a href="#" id="N" onclick="N(event)">N</a>
           <a href="#" id="O" onclick="O(event)">O</a>
           <a href="#" id="P" onclick="P(event)">P</a>
           <a href="#" id="Q" onclick="Q(event)">Q</a>
           <a href="#" id="R" onclick="R(event)">R</a>
           <a href="#" id="S" onclick="S(event)">S</a>
           <a href="#" id="T" onclick="T(event)">T</a>
           <a href="#" id="U" onclick="U(event)">U</a>

           <a href="#" id="V" onclick="V(event)">V</a>
           <a href="#" id="W" onclick="W(event)">W</a>
           <a href="#" id="X" onclick="X(event)">X</a>
           <a href="#" id="Y" onclick="Y(event)">Y</a>
           <a href="#" id="Z" onclick="Z(event)">Z</a>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
function A(event) {

   if (event.target.classList.contains("disabled")) {

     event.preventDefault();

   }

   document.getElementById("A").style.opacity = "0.5";

   event.target.classList.add("disabled");

   for (var letter = 0; letter <= randomWord.length - 1; letter++) {

     if (randomWord[letter] === "a") {

       document.getElementById("letter_" + letter).innerHTML = "A";

       if (oneClick === true) {

         score = score + 1;

         oneClick = false;

       }

       document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score;

     } else if (randomWord.indexOf("a") == -1 && hasLooped === true) {

       if (oneClick === true) {

         score = score + 1;

         oneClick = false;

       }

       document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score;

       hasLooped = false;

       mistakesLeft = mistakesLeft - 1;

       document.getElementById("attempsLeft").innerHTML = mistakesLeft;

       console.log(mistakesLeft);

       if (mistakesLeft == 7) {

         document.getElementById("part-1").style.display = "block";

       }

        else if (mistakesLeft == 6) {

         document.getElementById("part-2").style.display = "block";

       } else if (mistakesLeft == 5) {
         document.getElementById("part-3").style.display = "block";
       } else if (mistakesLeft == 4) {
         document.getElementById("part-4").style.display = "block";
       } else if (mistakesLeft == 3) {
         document.getElementById("part-5").style.display = "block";
       } else if (mistakesLeft == 2) {
         document.getElementById("part-6").style.display = "block";
       } else if (mistakesLeft == 1) {
         document.getElementById("part-7").style.display = "block";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("part-8").style.display = "block";
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

What changes will I need to make to my HTML and Javascript so I no longer need to have 26 different functions? The stuff with in my javascript will also need to change.
Thanks

Comment: `onclick='letterClicked(event, letter)'` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Change this a function so I can pass a id into it

Like you said, *"pass an id into it"*

```
onclick="oneFunction(event, this.id)"

function oneFunction(event, id){
  // one code
}
```

You don't even need `id`. Just pass in `this` and you've got your element.

Comment: But what about the rest of the Javascript- remember this function is for the letter A. For example what would I change here: if (randomWord[letter] === "a") { What can i replace that A with?

Answer (score 0):

You can also attach the function by `addEventListener` something like

**HTML**

`<a href="#" id="A" class="gamebutton">A</a>
 <a href="#" id="B" class="gamebutton">B</a>
 <a href="#" id="C" class="gamebutton">C</a>`

**JS**

```
var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('gamebutton');
//-------------as given in a tag as class----------^^^^
for(var i=0; i<allButtons.length; i++;){
    allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function (event){
        //the single function by which your game would be executed
        executeFunction(event, this.id);
        //the id(eg:- A, B, C)----^^^-- depends
        // on click is passing
    })
}
```